# How to login in WSO2 solutions using Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I integrate WSO2 solutions with Identity Server?

I need to use the same user of IS in all  WSO2 solutions.

I can't find nothing about this in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward is to share the user store among the all other WSO2 products you need the users to login.

If you have any other requirements that limits sharing the user store, you have to depend on some other mechanism like provisioning. In that case still you have to have an individual user's roles concept for each WSO2 solution for authorization purposes.

Comment: Ok, so I need to change in every service the source of users? How? If this is right I'll search about it.

Comment: You can do this by configuring the user-mgt.xml of all server to same user store. If the WSO2 servers are hosted behind the firewall in militarized zone with the user store, there won't be issues. But if servers are in demilitarized zone and you have to open ports in firewall to allow access to user store, this will be not much desired.

Comment: I try to use the same configuration LDAP in user-mgt.xml of Identity Service on .xml of EBS, but I can't start EBS now, the error is : `Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot create connection to LDAP server. Error message Error obtaining connection. localhost:10391` you know where can I find a example or tutorial?

Comment: I did the config! Thanks for your support.